# I need help making a longpress Context menu on android

Tags: android, contextmenu

Ok, so now after reading I do actually have a menu on long press like I wanted...the only problem is that it doesn't actually get the sound file and save it

I am wondering what did I do wrong now? Here is the code I used:

```
Button SoundButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.money);  
        registerForContextMenu(SoundButton1);
    }

     @Override  
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, 
                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) { 
            super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
            menu.setHeaderTitle("Save as..."); 
            menu.add(0, MENU_RINGTONE, 0, "Ringtone"); 
            menu.add(0, MENU_NOTIFICATION, 0, "Notification"); 
    } 

     @Override  
        public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {  
            if(item.getTitle()=="Ringtone"){function1(item.getItemId());}  
            else if(item.getTitle()=="Notification"){function2(item.getItemId());}  
            else {return false;}  
        return true;  
        }  

        public void function1(int id){  
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ringtone saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
        }  
        public void function2(int id){  
            Toast.makeText(this, "Notification saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not comparing `Strings` properly.  This test:

```
if(item.getTitle()=="Ringtone")
```

checks if the *object* returned by `getTitle()` is the same object as `"Ringtone"`.  This will always be `false`.  Similarly with the `else if` test.  You actually want to compare the *value* of `getTitle` with your `String`.  You should replace them with the `String#equals()` method.  Here is the code:

```
if(item.getTitle().equals("Ringtone")){function1(item.getItemId());}  
else if(item.getTitle().equals("Notification")){function2(item.getItemId());}  
else {return false;}
```

Comment: ok, ty but its still it wont save the ringtone when I emulate it on my phone eventhough I added return false; and private static final int MENU_NOTIFICATION = 0;
 private static final int MENU_RINGTONE = 0;

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a ListFragment then you also need to do

```
getListView().setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
```

instead of

```
registerForContextMenu(listView);
```

it seems.